# how do I protect a new engineered wood floor from sofa wheels

Tags: floor, protection

I'm getting a new engineered wood floor fitted next week and have an existing sofa with castor wheels at each corner. What's the best protection from damaging the floor? I don't want to put a mat under the sofa.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Must the sofa be able to roll?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous types of *[furniture cups](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Shepherd-1-1-2-in-Brown-Smooth-Rubber-Furniture-Cups-4-per-Pack-89075/100128991)* to cushion a floor against castors and legs.

[image: furniture cup]

Or you could just remove the castors.

```
 Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Comment: That is fine thank you. I think I'll put small pieces of carpet under each corner. Especially as i will have to move the sofa from time to time. Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: A fine solution. Just be sure that the carpeting gives you enough grip so that the couch does not slide every time somebody sits on it